# Nginx CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: reactjs, nginx, cors

I have configured the Nginx reverse proxy with below configuration:

```
location ^~ /api/my-service/ {
    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
    add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
    add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
    return 200;
 }
 if ($request_method = 'GET') {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization, DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
 }
}
```

When this service is called from a different origin, in the network tab i see the response of a service like:
http://nginx-host/api/my-service/users/user
and the response headers are:

```
Cache-Control   no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Type application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date    Tue, 10 Apr 2018 07:54:40 GMT
Expires 0
Pragma  no-cache
Server  nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding chunked
X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
X-Frame-Options DENY
X-XSS-Protection 1; mode=block
```

In the console of chrome/firefox i see:

```
Failed to load http://nginx-host/api/my-service/users/user: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://10.11.13.202:2200' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

This call is made from a react based application, shall i add something in the request headers as well in order to get this through.
The OPTIONS response has headers displayed properly:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization,DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 10 Apr 2018 08:08:53 GMT
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
```

Comment: Have you paid more attention to consistent URLs in your actual code, than you did here? Is it actually `/api/my-service/`, or `/api/user-service/`?

Comment: ok made it consistent in the question just tried to be generic and hence did a my-service here however the chrome log was copy pasted here so

Comment: And that request is actually a GET request? (The one the browser makes here, not what you are doing in your code.) You are adding a header saying three different methods are allowed, but have your node setup only handle one of those - why?

Comment: there are other methods as well like OPTIONS for which i have a configuration which has return as well.(if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {) Yes this particular request is a GET request,

Comment: This is still not consistent, you say you are looking at the response headers for `http://nginx-host/api/my-service/users/user` in the network tab, but the error message is about `http://10.21.12.116/api/my-service/users/user`

Comment: ok done, can i have some input on the problem please

Comment: strange thing is that i see a api request success on the network tab on chrome and respose of it as well...

Comment: What is the request method you see in the network panel? The amount of additional headers you are allowing for presumably makes this require a pre-flight request.

Comment: Updated the question, In fact i do not see the headers in the GET response my bad updating it again

Answer (score 0):

The API exposed is cheeky, for a GET request the response header is 202 accepted which ideally should have been 200, NGINX in this case does not append the response headers and messes up the configurations. Duh!

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use always alongside the * placeholder something like: 
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
works!